# Tracked request does not appear in analytics

Tags: c#, .net, azure-application-insights

I use TrackRequest to track some request in my code, the requests display on the dashboard but not in the analytics logs.

My TrackTrace works and does appear in the analytics dashboard, so i don't know what i'm doing wrong with TrackRequest.

```
RequestTelemetry request = new RequestTelemetry("**", DateTimeOffset.Now, stopwatch.Elapsed, null, true);
TelemetryClient logger = new TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration("**"));
logger.TrackRequest(request);
logger.Flush();
```

I expect to have the full list of the tracked request in the analytics logs. But actually it does not appear.

Comment: what do you mean it appears in dashboard(in the search in azure portal)? and you cannot get it from logs -> requests table?

Comment: @IvanYang It appear on the dashboard (screenshot here => https://i.ibb.co/1vYNJr5/server-request.png) but not on the log list (screenshot here => https://i.ibb.co/zQtmvK7/request.png)

Comment: It may be delayed. can you click the Analytics button on the top of the Overview page -> then in the log query, input requests, then click run to see if you can see the requests.

Comment: And if it's a console project, you can add Thread.Sleep(2*1000) before Flush.

Comment: @IvanYang I've done it and there is not results found (screenshot => https://i.ibb.co/PFRFd4X/requestnull.png). The traces appears well in the analytics  but not the requests. I tried to add Thread.Sleep(2*1000) before Flush but it does not change anything.

Comment: can you please add Thread.Sleep(2*1000); before the Flush method? I did the test with TrackRequest, it works fine at my side.

Comment: @IvanYang I've done it and I have same result. It Appear on the dashboard (server requests graph) but not in the analytics..

Comment: Weird. Are you using visual studio? if yes, when run the project, you can open the output window, to see if there are some output like : Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.xxxx.Request",xxxx}

Comment: the [screenshot](https://yy3.blob.core.windows.net/f11/vs.JPG) for output of visual studio

Comment: @IvanYang I'm using VS 2019 and here is what i get in theoutput window : https://i.ibb.co/SKsFjqX/output.png

Comment: @IvanYang It's really weird, I was not getting any requests data in analytics since 3 hours, and sudenly all requests appears at once.. I really don't understand how it is possible that no data is display for 3 hours and then boom everything is here. As it works now i would like to thanks you for your help Ivan

Comment: I had the problem before, sometimes it has delay(very long). But it's happy that the data comes.

Comment: I just summarized the case. Do you mind help mark it as answer? Thanks. It would be helpful for others who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarize:

As per the communication, the request data is really sent to AI server. But it has a long-time delay to display.